# Track configuration changes with Git and Puppet

Tags: git, puppet, server-configuration

We use Puppet to manage our Debian servers.

Our procedure is to have the `/etc` directory managed under Git and track any configuration changes on the servers (e.g. installing packages, adding new users, etc.)

When it comes to Puppet: is there a way to execute a `git commit .` with a meaningful commit message in `/etc` directory after Puppet has applied it's changes, preferably after each configuration change?

Does Puppet provide something like a hook to achieve the above?

Comment: Hang on a minute.  Is /etc "managed under Git" or does puppet manage "configuration change".  Puppet can run git with an Exec() type or git can run puppet with a post commit hook.  But you need to be clear who is in charge, what happens in the case of a rollback and so on

Comment: It is often policy that once Puppet is in force, it should be the **only** one making changes to `/etc/`, making etckeeper and friends obsolete. Your versioning happens on the Puppet code level then.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and comments. We use Git for auditing any changes to a server (we even use empty commits for adding a note about who and what has been done on a server). As we also do manual changes on a server (only the base configuration is done with Puppet), we can't leave it solely to Puppet. Further I learned that Puppet generates an execution plan based on dependencies, which makes my original idea impossible of having configuration changes grouped and tracked in logical units.

Answer (score 1):

Puppet has a configuration parameter [postrun_command](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/configuration.html#postruncommand) that you could theoretically run a script to do your git commit after every Puppet run (but not after every resource change as you asked).

However I agree with the other comments that it is a strange idea to mix Git and Puppet for configuration management. The only viable reason I can see for this is that you are using Git as a point-in-time audit trail only. I would recommend you look at Puppet's own [Auditing features](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/metaparameter.html#audit).

Comment: Thanks for your hint to [postrun_command](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/configuration.html#postruncommand) and [auditing features](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/metaparameter.html#audit) of Puppet. As mentioned by @LukeBigum we use Git for auditing changes on a server but that doesn't play well with Puppet (see my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321235/track-configuration-changes-with-git-and-puppet/30392537#comment48992949_30321235) above).